# What is another way to express recidivism but lose the criminal element?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a web site that performs calculations used to inform business owners how many of their customers are repeat customers.  The calculation will appear in a table, so I'd like the label to be short.  I thought the word *recidivism* would convey the idea, but I double-checked the definition and see that it applies to an offender's tendency to re-offend.  Is there a word that means the same but lacks the criminal implication?

Comment: You sound like you're asking for an alternative to fish without the water connection. _Loyalty_? In marketing parlance, it doesn't have the nobleness connection.

Comment: Well, "relapse" is a similar term, but not much better in terms of unwanted implications.

Comment: What about simply ***Repeat %*** or ***Repeat Customers***, ***Repeat Custs***,  ***Repeats*** etc.

Comment: Repetition, recurrence, habitual.

Comment: A *returnee* is someone who comes back.

Comment: [*Customer retention*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_retention) is a common term, but *retention* may not make sense as a column header.

Comment: **Revisit** may fit and is not ambiguous.

Comment: @Robert Simpson How about "repeater," i.e. one that repeats? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/repeater

Comment: Why not calculate it in the other direction?  *New Customers* vs *Customers*, which makes the meaning nice and clear.

Comment: @Robert Simpson Did you mean *residual* rather than your term *recidivism*?

Comment: relapse, 
    recurrence,
    regression,
    worsening,

    backsliding,
    fall,
    lapse,
    loss,

    repetition,
    retrogression,
    return,
    reversion,

    setback.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat customers is actually the perfect choice of phrase:

***[Repeat customer](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/repeat-customer)***

> Someone who buys again from a company that they have used before: Last
>   year, 55% of revenues came from repeat customers. At a restaurant with
>   a lot of repeat customers, a bad review might not make that much
>   difference.

(Cambridge)

If you want a shorter word:

> The calculation will appear in a table, so I'd like the label to be
>   short. I thought the word recidivism would convey the idea, but I
>   double-checked the definition and see that it applies to an offender's
>   tendency to re-offend.

Simply shorten to ***repeating***

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know where you got recidivism from, but it has nothing to do with this idea. It normally means the exceptional retention of some trait that is normally done away with. If you find an adult frog with gills, it is recidivistic. Cutsie dogs like the shih tzu look like puppies their whole life. They were selectively bred for recidivism. The use of the term with respect to criminals is a bit of a distraction.

In addition to Gary's answer, **loyal customer** is also very common. It has the advantage of you being able to be define it any way you choose. Maybe you want to track customers who have returned twice. You can define them as loyal customers. Someone who has returned once is still a repeat customer, but they don't meet your criterion.

> Primarily, customer loyalty is when a person transacts with a brand (or 
>   purchases a specific product) on an ongoing basis.
>
> [...]
>
> It’s up to each business to decide how it defines loyalty, whether
>   it’s transaction size or frequency, fidelity, evangelism or just
>   devoted engagement.

http://blog.accessdevelopment.com/what-is-the-definition-of-customer-loyalty